# Calculation of curvature in the level set method

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, mean-curvature-flows

I understand that the gradient of the unit normal vector is the curvature, but how was equation (4) in the link below derived?

https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.086/2007/levelsetnotes.pdf

Comment: Consider differentiation of $$\frac{1}{(\phi_x^2+\phi_y^2)^{1/2}}\binom{\phi_x}{\phi_y}$$

Comment: the answer for the question in the link below solve also my question, thank you.
<https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28821/divergence-of-gradient-of-the-unit-normal-and-curvature-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1>